# One out of N requests hangs for no visible reason after passing through event handlers

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api

In an overridden `HttpApplication.Init()` method I subscribed to 2 events as follows:

```
public override void Init()
{
    base.Init();

    BeginRequest += AnUsefulClass.OnBeginRequest;
    PreSendRequestHeaders += AnUsefulClass.OnPreSendRequestHeaders;
}
```

So I want some ad-hoc header to be added. The problem is that the response for *one* out of, say, 30 incoming requests hangs being even successfully processed (according to IIS logs and journals)

These event handlers do not have any mind-blowing logic within (but had before, of course):

```
public static void OnBeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //lock (Lock)
    {
        try
        {
            var app = sender as HttpApplication;

            if (app == null) return;

            // the logic was here
        }
        catch { }
    }
}

public static void OnPreSendRequestHeaders(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //lock (Lock)
    {
        try
        {
            var app = sender as HttpApplication;

            if (app == null) return;

            var context = app.Context;
            var response = context.Response;

            // the logic was here
        }
        catch { }
    }
}
```

I had been trying to apply custom implementation of `IHttpModule` with the same result though.

IIS Failed Request Tracing produces the report with the following tail:

```
=====================================================================================================================
167. GENERAL_FLUSH_RESPONSE_END BytesSent="782", ErrorCode="The operation completed successfully. (0x0)" 08:30:26.936
=====================================================================================================================
168. AspNetHttpHandlerLeave  08:30:26.936
=====================================================================================================================
```

Yet nothing more. Furthermore, I do see no suspicious words there. For me it takes forever to wait for the response. Yesterday's ones are still on their way home :)

Any help appreciated.

Comment: So this exact code you have posted is still causing an issue?

Comment: @Yura yes, exactly. It does nothing.

Comment: Can you confirm that if you remove this event handlers, code is not being stuck? Because what you have described (response being never returned) looks like a symptom of a deadlock somewhere in your controllers logic.

Comment: @Yura Yes, I confirm that. I commented out subscription statements, deployed and tested it hardly enough. No frozen ones :(

Comment: @Yura in the IIS trace I can see that the headers and body are composed well, so there were no deadlocks in a managed layer. But there is something 'behind the scenes'.

Comment: Is it ~30 parallel requests that cause an issue, or is it ~30 sequential, with one that fails?

Comment: @Yura well, basically it might be one request out of 5-10-N that fails, or not only one 'lost' but even 2-3 in a row, or 50 requests with no 'fails'. Can't say there is a predictable correlation between number of sent and number of lost.

Comment: Have you managed to fix your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/aspnet/overview/web-development-best-practices/what-not-to-do-in-aspnet-and-what-to-do-instead#presend), "PreSendRequestHeaders" event can cause unpredictable issues when combining with managed modules, which WebApi is.

Very same problem (but different scenario) is described in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24668835/debugging-signalr-hang).

Anyway, if your goal is to add some header to response, you can safely use ActionFilter for WebApi.

Comment: sorry for the delay with an answer :) Yes, symptoms described in a related thread look exceptionally the same. I've made a deep googling around that and it all comes to an unpredictable behavior of `PreSendRequestHeaders` event in different cases. Thus we decided to adjust the existing flow to let us use `ActionFilter`s instead.